# Resetting iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an application that is currently named "xxxx". The app runs and works perfectly without any problems. However, I have reached a stumbling point. When I try to load the application onto my iPhone, the pictures on my picker view seemed to have disappeared for some strange reason. I've done multiple hours of debugging and everything checks out normal. I then decided I wanted to change the product name from "xxxx" to "xxxx Redo". As soon as I did that, the application loaded perfectly normal (with the pictures in the Picker View as it should be).

In conclusion, it comes to find out that there is no actual bug in the programming aspect of it. However, my question comes up as to why does it not load the correct way with the original product name but then loads the right way when the product name is changed?

The second part of my question is if anyone knows of a way to fix the original application so that way it displays correctly again with the original name?

I have tried the following:

- Cleaning the app
- Trashing the .app file and rebuilding
- Deleting the app on the iPhone and rebuilding.

Comment: @mvds Thanks for the extra advice. I did the clean build folder by pressing alt and it worked. Would you like for me to leave this question up as something useful and mark you down as the correct answer or just delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things sometimes just happen, you can try the following extra steps:

- clean build folder in XCode (press alt while clicking Product menu)
- reboot the phone (poweroff/poweron)

I have seen cases where it made a difference.